# How to remove a drawn bitmap in android?

Tags: android

In my program, the right tube is drawn first, after that the left one is drawn too

my goal is how to remove (Clear / Hide ... ) the first drawn tube, and keep only the second one

NB : I have already checked many topics related to the canvas Drawing, but nothing works

Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lofs.png

My Method :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas cv) {

       Bitmap haut = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.haut);

       cv.drawBitmap(haut, 300, 0, null);

       // WHAT SHOULD I ADD HERE TO CLEAR THE FIRST TUBE  

       cv.drawBitmap(haut, 0, 0, null);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redraw the background and draw just one tube. No way to 'hide' it from drawn canvas unless it is not in separate view.

Answer (score 3):

You can create another empty bitmap and assign it to the related image view.

it will remove the first Bitmap:

```
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.your_imageview_id);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(0 , 0 , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
iv.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw all the same images again excluding the first image and then call `invalidate()` which will call `onDraw()`. When you work at low level drawings in canvas, you need to redraw everything for each change and invalidate..